# Disabling click for one data adapter in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am using CWAC MergeAdapter - https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge to add two data adapters in a `ListView`. Something like this:

```
MergeAdapter mergeAdapter = new MergeAdapter();
mergeAdapter.addAdapter(yourFirstAdapter);
mergeAdapter.addAdapter(yourSecondAdapter);
list.setAdapter(mergeAdapter);
```

I also setup an item click listener for my `ListView`. However what I want is that only data from adapter1 should be clickable. How can I implement this. What i have so far is this:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

RelativeLayout secondAdapterlistRowLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.secondrow);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long mallId) {
            //go to the shops view
            if (adapterView.equals(secondAdapterlistRowLayout)){
                //do nothing
            }
            else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ShopActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("MALL_ID", (int) mallId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

    });
```

**XML -- row2 -- adapter2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F0F0F0"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:id="@+id/secondrow">
    ....
</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically i want to do this:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long mallId) {

         if(R.id.secondrow is clicked){ then start a new activity }

        }
      }
```

Comment: check if clicked item is not in  `yourFirstAdapter` then do some code otherwise ignore onItemClick

Comment: Are those adapters custom? If yes then override `isEnabled` and return false in the adapter whose items you dont want clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way that i found was to get the resource name that was clicked and then compare it with the resource name of the row (i.e. secondrow)

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long mallId) {

         if (getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId()).equals("secondrow"){
                     //then do something
            }
        //otherwise do nothing
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In adapter view use setTag() method to your item and identify that tag when your click on listview any item.